# What happened to the open bench logic sniffer?

Tags: logic-analyzer, open-hardware

Around 2015 the Open Bench Logic Sniffer looked like a really promising logic sniffer/analyzer at a price a hobbyist could tolerate. These were available assembled from Seeed (and others?) There's no sign of it today that I can find. Is there a successor that obsoleted this? Is there a competitively priced commercial offering that is a good substitute?

Not that I really want to build one, but I can't find board layout files (KiCAD or other) or gerbers, even though the project is described as open source. The code files are there, but not schematics and board layout.

Comment: eh?   It was retired along with others that became profitable https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=saleae&hvadid=74560704688537&hvbmt=be&hvdev=c&hvqmt=e&tag=msncahydra-20&ref=pd_sl_6usf8u855w_e

Comment: here are some "exploded" schematics http://dangerousprototypes.com/docs/Hardware_design_overview

Answer (score 1):

I found a successor to Open Bench Logic Sniffer here :
http://store.gadgetfactory.net/papilio-fpga-logic-analyzer-bundle/

But if someone finds a place to buy original mounted Open Bench Logic Sniffer, I'm interested ! As we already use 10 of them  for education, and buying some more would be nice...

Answer (score 0):

The theory behind this will be at: https://www.sump.org/projects/analyzer/ .

You could optionally try the following: https://hackaday.io/project/25745-beaglelogic-standalone.  Search OSHPark for "BeagleLogic Standalone".  Project at: https://github.com/abhishek-kakkar/BeagleLogic